# How to filter nested array?

Tags: javascript

How to filter nested array? I have an array with users, I need to display the roles of the selected user in , but it turns out to be a huge nesting and a whole bunch of iterations, how to avoid this and get something like:

```
const options = [
  { value: 1, label: "admin" },
  { value: 0, label: "moderator" }
];
```

***I do***

```js
const arr = [
{
  users: [
    {
      id: 1,
      login: "alex",
        roles: [
          { id: 0, name: "admin" },
          { id: 1, name: "moderator" }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        login: "bob",
        roles: [{ id: 0, name: "viewer" }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const rolesOptions = arr.filter(({ users }) =>
  users
    .filter(({ id }) => id === 1)
    .map(({ roles }) =>
      roles.map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: name, value: id }))
    )
);

console.log(rolesOptions);
```

Comment: Just want to confirm that admin and moderator values should be 0 and 1, not 1 and 0?

Comment: what is `value`in `options` doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to map your outer `arr` of object. For each inner nested object, you can filter it to only keep objects matching the `id` of `1` (as you've done). You can then use `.flatMap()` on the filtered inner array to map each role to its re-keyed object with `label` and `name`. The `.flatMap()` methods then merge the returned array results into one resulting array:

```js
const arr = [ { users: [ { id: 1, login: "alex", roles: [ { id: 0, name: "admin" }, { id: 1, name: "moderator" } ] }, { id: 2, login: "bob", roles: [{ id: 0, name: "viewer" }] } ] } ];
const options = arr.flatMap(({users}) => users
  .filter(({ id }) => id === 1)
  .flatMap(({roles}) => roles.map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: name, value: id })))
);
console.log(options);
```

If you know for certain that there can only be *one* user object within each object's `users` array with a given `id`, then you can make your code more efficient by using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) so that it returns as soon as the object user with the id is found:

```js
const arr = [{ users: [{ id: 1, login: "alex", roles: [{ id: 0, name: "admin" }, { id: 1, name: "moderator" }] }, { id: 2, login: "bob", roles: [{ id: 0, name: "viewer" }] }] }];

const options = arr.flatMap(({users}) => users
  .find(({ id }) => id === 1)
  ?.roles.map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: name, value: id })) ?? []
);

console.log(options);
```

The above uses [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) to check that an user with the id can be found, and the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) to return an empty array if the `id` coudln't be found.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to use `map` instead of `filter` on the outside array `arr`

`flat` then flattens the remaining objects

```js
  const arr = [
    {
      users: [
        {
          id: 1,
          login: "alex",
          roles: [
            { id: 0, name: "admin" },
            { id: 1, name: "moderator" }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          login: "bob",
          roles: [{ id: 0, name: "viewer" }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const rolesOptions = arr.map(({ users }) =>
    users
      .filter(({ id }) => id === 1)
      .map(({ roles }) =>
        roles.map(({ id, name }) => ({ label: name, value: id }))
      )
  ).flat(2);
  
  console.log(rolesOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to achieve what you want:

```js
const arr = [ { users: [ { id: 1, login: "alex", roles: [ { id: 0, name: "admin" }, { id: 1, name: "moderator" } ] }, { id: 2, login: "bob", roles: [{ id: 0, name: "viewer" }] } ] } ];
const selectUser = (id)=>{
  const user = arr[0].users.find(user => user.id === id);
  if(!user) return {};
  return user.roles.map(r=> ({value:r.id, label : r.name})).sort((v1,v2)=>v2.value-v1.value)
}

console.log(selectUser(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
const arr = [
  {
    users: [
      {
        id: 1,
        login: "alex",
        roles: [
          { id: 0, name: "admin" },
          { id: 1, name: "moderator" }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        login: "bob",
        roles: [{ id: 0, name: "viewer" }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const users = getUsers(arr)

const rolesOptions = getRolesOptions(users)

console.log(rolesOptions)

function getUsers(arr) {
  let res = [] // The result array

  arr
    .filter(({ users }) => users) // Filters to find every instance that has a "users" JSON key
    .map(({ users }) => users) // Maps out the users into multiple arrays
    .forEach(users => { // Adds each array of users into one array
      users.forEach(user => {
        res.push(user)
      })
    })

  return res
}

function getRolesOptions(users) {
  let res = []  // The result array

  users.forEach(user => {
    user.roles.forEach(({ name, id }) => { // For every user it pushes the role in formate { name, id } to the result array
      res.push({ label: name, value: id })
    })
  })

  return res
}
```

There probably is a neater way. Sorry if it is not what you asked for